# Django Logging error

Tags: django, apache, logging

I am using the default logger in Django in `models.py` like this.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='models.log',level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Staring execution. Models for db tables')
```

It is working in the Django server and logs are getting written. When the app is being deployed on Apache, I get a `500 Internal Server error` and cannot even load the home page.

The OS is RHEL7. I have changed the file permission of "models.log" to read-write". Still I face the issue. In apache conf file, I have granted permissions as well.

Comment: run in debug=true mode and check what exactly is the problem

Comment: Post the error. ll try to help you.

Comment: Its working on Django server. Not working on Apache. Is there any need to change the wsgi.py file for sys.path?

Comment: Plz post more info about errors.

Comment: The error is 500 internal server error only.. Nothing else. Apache logs also don't display any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem related with `SELinux`. If You run locally, then You have full rights to write to log file.

If You run server with apache, then apache must have full rights to write to file.

To check it, login as apache `sudo su - apache` and try to access to log file.

Solution is simple: put log file in `/var/log` folder. Or create `/var/log/myapp` folder and give it full access `chmod 777 /var/log/myapp`.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/myapp/models.log',level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Staring execution. Models for db tables')
```

Answer (score 0):

The process needs *execute* (not only read) access on the directory and parent directories. The best way would be to log in as the user the process is running and try to create the file manually. My guess is you will get a permission error. Create the directories and grant relevant permissions for the directories.